# Checking if value exists in ArrayList in a different class without creating a new list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bukkit

I've been having some trouble with ArrayList's over the past few days. Essentially, here's my ArrayList class:

**ChatUtil Class**

```
private ArrayList<UUID> waitingForSlowInput = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<UUID> getWaitingForSlowInput(){
    return waitingForSlowInput;
}

public void addWaitingForSlowInput(UUID u){
    getWaitingForSlowInput().add(u);
}

public void removeWaitingForSlowInput(UUID u){
    getWaitingForSlowInput().remove(u);
}
```

In this class, I also have a method that uses the addWaitingForSlowInput method, so the player gets added to the ArrayList.

Then, in a separate class, I'm checking to see if this ArrayList contains the UUID by doing this:

**Other Class**

```
chatUtil = new chatUtil(); // Getting class with ArrayList, but removes everything in List

if(chatUtil.getWaitingForSlowInput().contains(p.getUniqueId())){
// and then I continue the code, but list will never contain the UUID because it's empty
```

The problem: When I'm getting the ArrayList in the class above, it's creating a new instance of the list, removing the player's UUID.

This (obviously) works when I use static, but I'd rather stay away from static abuse. The only other option I could think of would be to set up a Singleton, but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The class that needs to check it needs to receive a reference to the `ChatUtil`. You haven't shown us anything of the surrounding context, but the most obvious solution is to pass a reference to the `ChatUtil` into the constructor of the thing that needs to check it.

Comment: Ok, here's some more context. This is the ChatUtil class: https://hastebin.com/sukefojohi.cs , and this is the class where I need to check the ArrayList: https://hastebin.com/hasagemisa.java . Line 24 and 27 of ChatListener are referencing the ChatUtil class (renamed to ChatGUIUtil, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: I can't access those sites, but can you just pass the instance of the ChatUtil into the thing that needs it? You don't want to create a new ChatUtil; that creates a new list. (In your question you say "removes everything in List", but of course it isn't removing anything, it's just creating a completely different list).

Comment: @DavidConrad Excuse me for the dumb question (I'm quite new to java), but how would I pass an instance from one class to another class without doing "chatUtil = new ChatUtil()"

Comment: @DavidConrad Wait! I think I figured it out, let me test it. I know what you mean now.

Comment: @DavidConrad Nope, still clearing the ArrayList when trying to access from other class. I removed the "new ChatUtil" and added this to the beginning of the other class:

`private ChatGUIUtil chatGUIUtil;`

    `public ChatListener(ChatGUIUtil chatGUIUtil){`
       `this.chatGUIUtil = chatGUIUtil;`
   `}`

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `new chatutil()`, you're creating a [new instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) of that class, and therefore, it doesn't carry over the data from any other instance of that class.

You can solve this by defining a static instance of the class in your main, something like:

Main class

```java
private static ChatUtil CHAT_UTIL;

public void onEnable(){
    CHAT_UTIL = new ChatUtil();
}

public static ChatUtil getChatUtil(){
    return CHAT_UTIL;
}
```

Then in your other classes, you could do something like this; where `MyPlugin` is your main class

```java
MyPlugin.getChatUtil().getWaitingForSlowInput(); //...etc...
```

Java [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html#15411) for classes is PascalCase so I've renamed your `chatUtil` class to `ChatUtil` in the example.

Comment: Isn't using static bad practice? Or would it be okay in this scenario?

Comment: Many other sites for Bukkit/Spigot development have villainized the `static` keyword but its use, in this case, is justified because you wish to access the `ChatUtil` class like a manager and so you need a static reference to it.